# Symfony 1.4 form is not rendering on template

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

My symfony 1.4 application's form is not rendering on template.Template is loading properly.Without form attributes it's loading nicely.When add a new form in controller and load it to the template only i'm getting a blank page.Why is that?

Update:

Following is my php error log content.

```
Fatal error: Class 'LoginForm' not found in C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\apps\symfony_app\modules\user_login\actions\actions.class.php on line 21

PHP Stack trace:

{main}() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\web\index.php:0

sfContext->dispatch() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\web\index.php:7

sfFrontWebController->dispatch() C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\pear\symfony\util\sfContext.class.php:170

sfController->forward() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:2352

sfFilterChain->execute() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:665

sfRenderingFilter->execute() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:1031

sfFilterChain->execute() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:995

sfExecutionFilter->execute() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:1031

sfExecutionFilter->handleAction() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:933

sfExecutionFilter->executeAction() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:947

sfActions->execute() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:952

user_loginActions->executeIndex() C:\wamp\www\symfony_app\cache\symfony_app\prod\config\config_core_compile.yml.php:459
```

Comment: Have you checked php error log?

Comment: It sounds like you have debugging turned off. Turn it back on to see the error.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments.I have updated the question above with the error log content.

Comment: Thanks everyone who commented.Finally i could solve it by my own.I'm posting the answer in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which i came up with to this.I was first created a seperate form class by extending symfony base form.At that point my form didn't worked.So i added the form's attributes inside the controller's action method instead of defining it in a seperate file.Now it's working fine.

```
class loginActions extends sfActions
{
/**
* Executes index action
*
* @param sfRequest $request A request object
*/
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  $this->form = new sfForm();
  $this->form->setWidgets(array(
    'name'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
    'password'   => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(),
   ));
  }


}
```

Update form class content:

```
class LoginForm extends BaseForm
{
   public function configure()
    {
      $this->setWidgets(array(
      'name'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'password'   => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(),
      ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally it's best to create a class which extends the `sfForm` and in the `configure()` function put the definitions of fields and validators.

Comment: Yeah i know.Previously i was done in that way.But it didn't worked.That's why i tried in this way.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski : Do you know why i can't extend the base form and get the form?It's not working in my application.I also think it's better to do in that way as you said.

Comment: Symfony should include your classes automatically. I'm not sure why you had problems with that. Can you write what was the name of your file with the form's definition, where was it and what was the name of the class inside it (maybe you made a typo).

Comment: Yes sure i'll.my custom form is inside the /apps/mymodule/lib/form/LoginForm.class.php.I'll update my question with the code inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Now the form thing is working.Previously i was checked with url,

```
http://localhost/symfony_app/web/login/index.
```

In this way it didn't worked.But after i access through,

```
http://localhost/symfony_app/web/symfony_app_dev.php/login/index.
```

When accessing through this url it's working.

Comment: So it's cache. You need to clear the cache when you add or remove classes.

Comment: No.I have disabled the cache.So it can't be as i think.Anyhow thsi issue is fine.Not a big issue for my development.If you can please give me a help for this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308016/symfony-1-4-doctrine-model-object-data-retrieve-issue