# Symfony 1.4 doctrine model object data retrieve issue

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

In my symfony 1.4 application i'm using doctrine data models.I'm new to symfony and doctrine.I generated doctrine models from command-line after defining database table information in the schema.yml file.Those generated successfully.Then i created a custom function inside Table.class.php file.Following is that.

```
class Table extends BaseTable
{
 public function getuname()
 {
    $user=new Table();
    $uname=$user->getUsername();
    return $uname;
 }

}
```

I want to know how to call this inside the controller ? I called it normal MVC application's way.But i don't know whether it's correct in symfony.In symfony 1.4 manual also i couldn't find a proper way to do this.

This is my controller.

```
class loginActions extends sfActions
{

  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
     $this->userdata = User::getuname();
  }

}
```

Then i tried to print this inside view.

```
<?php 
   echo $userdata;
?>
```

But view is showing an empty page.

Update with exception details--------------------------------

stack trace
at ()
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php line 1082 ...

```
    $message .= sprintf('. Failing Query: "%s"', $query);

    }


    $exc  = new $name($message, (int) $e->getCode());

    if ( ! isset($e->errorInfo) || ! is_array($e->errorInfo)) {

        $e->errorInfo = array(null, null, null, null);

    }
```

Comment: You should read about table and model classes: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Doctrine#chapter_08_sub_object_and_table_classes There are examples how to use them. And you can find some help in the doctrine docs as well http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes actually i followed the symfony document that you have posted.But my problem is as i can see there i can't find a way to call the model object inside the symfony controller.But anyhow again i'll go through the doc thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

When using Doctrine you retrieve objects from the database using the `...Table` classes (in your case it will be a `TableTable` class. You can use its' methods to fetch objects from DB (e.g. `find($id)`) and then access them. So in your case your classes should something like this:

```
class Table extends BaseTable
{
    public function getuname()
    {
       return $this->getUsername();
    }
}
```

Now it effectively becomes just an alias of `getUsername()`.

Then in your action:

```
class loginActions extends sfActions
{

    public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        $user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Table')->find(123);
        $this->userdata = $user->getuname();
    }
}
```

This will print the username in your template (assuming of course that you have a user with id `123`).

Comment: First thanks for your reply.Yes i call the model inside the controller as you have mentioned.I have a user with user id 1.Therefore i change the line according to this.$user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Table')->find('1');After that when loads the page it shows a 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception error.

Comment: It should be `find(1)` not `find('123')` (I corrected this in my answer), though I'm not sure this causes the error. Can you paste any more information you get about the exception?

Comment: Yeah it can't be.Anyhow i changed it and checked.But not worked.When i'm searching online regarding this i saw somewhere in stackoverflow itself had this kind of question.Somebody has answered there can be a database connectivity issue and check mysql socket.I checked it also.It's there.If there's a database connectivity issue when i'm building the schema through command-line i should get an error.But i didn't got any and build was successful.So i'm confusing what is the issue?

Comment: When you generate model classes based on your `schema.yml` file then no connection to DB is made. Check your connection settings if you really have access to the database. Also read carefully through the error information - usually you can the important details there.